# Галерея Masonry (плитка) c одинаковой высотой "строк". Как на "Яндекс-Картинках". Как этого добиться?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, плагин, jquery-tools

Подскажите, есть ли плагины для генерации галереи вроде такой:
 [image]

- с равной высотой "строк"
- динамически определяющейся шириной изображений, которая точно подгоняет ширину "строки" под размер экрана.

Пример такого решения в реализации - Яндекс-Картинки (https://yandex.ua/images/search?text=nature&rdrnd=333104)

Искал подобные настройки в плагине Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) и аналогах - пока не удалось найти.

Какие могут быть еще решения вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) плагин. Хотя, я слышал, что Flickr выложил в общий доступ этот код. Но найти не могу пока.

Comment: Спасибо. Плюс поставил. По правилам stackoverflow он должен вам добавиться, когда моя собственная репутация станет больше 15.